# Capturing a button before removing it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have created a jsfiddle as I thought it would be the best way to show the problem.  Basically, the script can change the button, but after the button changes, the header does not change.  I am assuming it's because the original button is been replaced:

http://jsfiddle.net/cEu8f/5/

Is it possible to somehow capture the original button so it can be used to remove replace the header even after the button has been removed?

Comment: What do you mean by *'capture'*?

Comment: I just want the second line in the function to work, even after the button has been removed.  Don't know how else to describe "capture".

Comment: Maybe capture an instance of the button?

Comment: Why do you need to capture the button? You're not extracting any information from the button markup, you're just using it as a selector for markup that isn't changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function like below,

```
function some_function( that ) {
    var $outerDiv = that.closest('.outer_div');
    $outerDiv.find('.main').empty().append( '<input type="button" id="some_other_button" value="click me 2" />' );    
    $outerDiv.find('.header').empty().append( "new header data" );
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cEu8f/6/)

Answer (score 3):

You can [cache](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/19/speed-up-the-jquery-code-selectors-cache/) the `outer_div` element ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cEu8f/8/));

```
$('#some_button').live('click', function() {
    some_function( $(this) );
});

function some_function( that ) {
    var $outer_div = that.closest('.outer_div');

    $outer_div
        .find('.main')
        .empty()
        .append( '<input type="button" id="some_other_button" value="click me 2" />' )
        .end()
        .find('.header')
        .empty()
        .append( "new header data" );
}
```

Also notice the [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end) function. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `that` element does not exist anymore when you remove it from DOM. However, you can "cache" parent `div` element.

```
function some_function( that ) {
    var div = that.closest('.outer_div');
    div.find('.main').empty().append( '<input type="button" id="some_other_button" value="click me 2" />' );     
    div.find('.header').empty().append( "new header data" );
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cEu8f/7/